# SQL Server and iPad app interaction

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, ipad, api

I have to write an app for iPad that would take data from SQL Server and post it to the iPad.  I looked up on this over the Internet and found that i have to write a web service to expose the data from SQL server using ASP.NET. I did an app previously in android that would take data from my dropbox a/c and display it to the user. I made use of the drop-box api available. I was wondering if anything like that exists for SQL? Also, i have to code in Obj-C for the iPad, so how will 
i write ASP.NET code? I have more doubts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OData. See [Creating an OData API for StackOverflow including XML and JSON in 30 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx) for how to publish your SQL Server data as an OData service. See [Consuming OData using Objective-C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/Video/gg602479) for how to consume the OData service from your iPhone app.

Comment: .Thanks. I actually was doing research and working with the links you provided. I used the first link to extract data from the SQL DB and showed it on my browser. I gotta try the second one. I am new to Obj-C, here's hoping i figure it out.

Comment: I was going through the second link (Consuming OData using Obj-c) and i couldn't understand the part creating a proxy. It was not clear. Can you explain it a little more.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for web services. If you are developing in ASP.NET and don't want to invest to much time in just accessing the data I would suggest some software that will help you generate the source code.

WSSF (Web Service Software Factory) is software that will assist you in creating a SOAP web service and it generates source code for you. I do recommend however working through a tutorial first before just jumping into using this. WSSF uses visual studio as well.

Once you have a web service that packages your SQL data for communication through http requests. You will need to parse the data communicated in Objective-C. For this you'll find SudzC to be very helpful.

SudzC generates all the source code for accessing your web service in Objective-C, given the WSDL.xml file of your web service (a file that lays out the design of your web service).

Although these software will save you a lot of coding, I wish I could tell you that this will be a short and easy process. However this is vary rarely the case, developing this will take you a couple of days.

I do know that people often use RESTful web services when dealing with the iOS enviroment, although I do not have the same kind of experience with them as I do SOAP web services. I hope that this information is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this.  The best way is to use .NET 3.5 or higher to create a WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) project.  These projects will let you communicate with your mobile application using REST or SOAP.  They also let you send data in XML or JSON format.  You will then need to create a REST or SOAP client in your IPad application to communicate with the server.

Comment: @Z. Thanks for the info. I am new to WCF. So how should i proceed?I looked up tutorials over the internet but they are confusing me more.

Comment: First I gathered what I could from the MSDN website.  I didn't understand everything that they said but that was ok.  I just learned what I needed to meet my goals.  I then picked up a book from barnes and noble which really made things easier to understand.  Lastly I set up a demo project to see how it worked. For my first WCF project I basically just modified the demo project.  They have several demo projects on the MSDN website.